# Fundamentally misunderstanding alignment and setw?

Tags: c++

I'm asking this after googling for 2 hours now. As the title says I think I'm misunderstanding how to use the two things above. I'm attempting to create two distinct columns that show output and are in line with one another. However it seems no matter what I do they won't line up.

My code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double THEATHERCUT = .80;
    const double DISTRIBUTORCUT = .20;
    const int CHILDCOST = 6;
    const int ADULTCOST = 10;

    string movieName;

    int childTickets, adultTickets, childGrossRevenue, adultGrossRevenue, totalGrossRevenue, distributorRevenue, totalNetRevenue;

    //User Input
    cout << "What movie was viewed?" << endl;
    getline(cin, movieName);
    cout << "How many adult tickets were sold?" << endl;
    cin >> adultTickets;
    cout << "How many child tickets were sold?" << endl;
    cin >> childTickets;

    // Maths

    childGrossRevenue = (CHILDCOST * childTickets);
    adultGrossRevenue = (ADULTCOST * adultTickets);

    totalGrossRevenue = (childGrossRevenue + adultGrossRevenue);
    distributorRevenue = (totalGrossRevenue * .20);
    totalNetRevenue = (totalGrossRevenue * .80);

    cout << left << "Movie Name:" << setw(20) << right << movieName << endl;
    cout << left << "Adult Tickets Sold:" << setw(20) << right << adultTickets << endl;
    cout << left << "Child Tickets Sold:" << setw(20) << right << childTickets << endl;
    cout << left << "Gross Box Office Revenue:" << setw(20) << right << totalGrossRevenue << endl;
    cout << left << "Amount Paid to Distributor:" << setw(20) << right << distributorRevenue << endl;
    cout << left << "Net Box Office Revenue:" << setw(20) << right << totalNetRevenue << endl;

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

As far as my understanding goes the first cout line should do the following:

Align "Movie Name:" to the left, `setw(20)` set a 20 space padding between the "Movie Name:" and movieName. right then justifies movieName to the right. Is this correct? Just for clarification this is how I'd like it to look.

[image: Example]

(I'm also well aware using `system("pause")` is sacrilegious before anyone mentions it.)

Comment: Instead of "Googling for 2 hours", have you tried studying the documentation and learning from your C++ textbook?

Comment: No, admittedly I did not. You make a good point, I should consult that before asking. But still, your input clarified it for me and works. I'll be sure to do that in the future before asking. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck in your studies!

Answer (score 3):

> setw(20) set a 20 space padding between the "Movie Name:" and movieName. right then justifies movieName to the right. Is this correct?

No.

`setw(20)` sets the next "field" to be 20-characters wide, triggering the insertion of additional whitespace if the field is shorter (resulting in an "alignment" effect in the output of subsequent fields).

This must come *before* the field is inserted otherwise you have a temporal paradox.

The field you're trying to pad is the "Movie Name:" part, so move your `setw`s one to the left.

`left` and `right` align *within* a field, which doesn't seem to be what you are after, so drop `right`.

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9485de035047c28)*)

<sub>* I have killed two unused variables, fixed indentation, remove sacrilegiousness (I literally had to or this demo wouldn't work — *evil*!), and increased your spacing (since 20 isn't actually enough to fit column 1 in all your rows). Otherwise the changes are only as recommended above.</sub>